# Asymptotics of solution of first order ODE with regular singular point

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I have several first order systems of ODEs of the following form:

$x \partial_x u + x B u - Z u = 0$

where $u: (0, + \infty) \to \mathbb C^N$, $B,Z$ are *Hermitian* rank $N$ matrices, and $\det B \not = 0$. These operators are "toy models" for certain "singular" Dirac operators.

If the matrices $Z$ and $B$ commute, it is very easy to find all the solutions. $Z$ and $B$ can be simultaneously unitarily diagonalized, so we have the special solutions $x^\alpha e^{- \beta x} u_0$, where $u_0$ is a common eigenvector for $Z$ and $B$ with eigenvalues $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Any solution is a linear combination of these special solutions.

In the general case, when $Z$ and $B$ do not commute, we can still solve the equation formally. We start with an eigenvector $u_0$ for $Z$ relative to the eigenvalue $\alpha$, and (assuming for simplicity that $\alpha + n$ is not an eigenvalue of $Z$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$) we can define iteratively $ u_n = (Z - \alpha - n)^{-1} B u_{n-1}$ and the power series

$u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha + n} u_n $

defines a formal solution. (If $\alpha + n$ is an eigenvalue of $Z$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, one can write down a similar expansion, but involving logarithmic terms).

Now, some experiment with this kind of systems led me to believe that *the series above has always an infinite radius of convergence*, and that the asymptotic behavior of the sum as $ x \to \infty$ is either exponential, or negative exponential.

I have two questions:

1. **Are the observations above correct? Is it true that the series above has always an infinite radius of convergence, and the sum is either asymptotically exponential or asymptotically negative exponential?**
2. **If the answer of the first question is *yes*, can I predict the behavior at infinity of the sum in terms of the decomposition of the leading coefficient $u_0$ in terms of the spectral decomposition of $B$?**

Thank you all.